# html not appearing for Applet

Tags: java, html, applet

I tried creating an html file for my applet, but nothing appears.

this is the code to my applet

```
public class TimeSet extends Applet{

    public TimeSet(){
        //set the title
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("2 hour time set");

        //specify what happens when the close button is clicked
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //set main panel where all other panels will exist in
        mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,1));
        add(mainPanel);

        timePanel();
        ammountPanel();
        durationPanel();
        buttonSet();

        setVisible(true);

    }
```

and this is the code i'm using for my htm

```
<Html>
<Head>
<Title>TimeSet</Title>
</Head>

<Body>
<Applet Code="TimeSet.class" width=200 Height=100>
</Applet>
</Body>
</Html>
```

is there a problem with my code or is there a different process? the html file is in the same folder as the TimeSet.class file. When I run the applet, it works fine

Comment: Don't use the applet at all. Instead launch the frame from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two entry point methods, `init()` and `start()`, which Java will call on behalf of your Applet.  In your case, try adding an `init()` method to your Applet, which in turn calls your `TimeSet()` method:

```
public class TimeSet extends Applet{

    public void init () {
        TimeSet();
    }

    public void TimeSet(){
        //set the title
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("2 hour time set");

        //specify what happens when the close button is clicked
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //set main panel where all other panels will exist in
        mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,1));
        add(mainPanel);

        timePanel();
        ammountPanel();
        durationPanel();
        buttonSet();

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

By the way, as others will likely comment here, Applet is a deprecated technology and you should not plan on using it in a release product.

Comment: it's producing an error that says TimeSet() is undefined. And yeah, its for a class, otherwise i would never use it

Comment: Sorry, I omitted a return type for `TimeSet()` (because you also did and I just blindly copied your code).  Try it again now.

Comment: Still nothing appearing in the html

Comment: There be another problem with your applet code.  I'm not an expert in Applet, I just fixed the major problems you were having.

Comment: Try using `frame.show()`, this might make it appear.